# VBA usedrange run-time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro involving usedrange. Basically my sub tries to open up a text file with opentext and copy the formulas in the text file and paste over to the worksheet "SOE Summary" of my destination workbook. However, a run-time error 438 would occur when I try to set the formulas of my worksheet "SOE Summary" equal to the formulas in the text file. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
Sub Sample()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook 


Dim fileToOpen As Variant 'Txt file that contains formulas
Dim fileName As String _
'Name of the temporary workbook that contains formulas from fileToOpen
Dim sheetName As String _
'Name of the worksheet of the temporary workbook that contains formulas from fileToOpen
fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt") _
'User selects the txt file that contains formulas
If fileToOpen <> False Then 'Make sure the user selects a txt file
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True 'Transport formulas into a temporary workbook
End If
fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1) _
'Name of the temporary workbook
sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) _
'Name of the temporary worksheet


Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Disable any popup windows
WB.Sheets("SOE Summary").UsedRange.Value = Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(sheetName).UsedRange.Formula_
'[ERROR 438 OCCURRED] Paste formulas into "SOE Summary" worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'Enable popup windows after the previous line of code


Workbooks(fileName).Close savechanges:=False 'Close the temporary workbook and discard any changes
WB.Sheets("SOE Summary").UsedRange.Value = WB.Sheets("SOE Summary").UsedRange.Value _
'Replace all formulas in the "SOE Summary" worksheet with values
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the `_` at the end of most of these lines. It just happens to be allowed until your error line because `.Formula_` doesn't have the necessary space before the underscore. I.e. `.Formula _`

Comment: @CallumDA  Oh my god, I was so stupid my friend. Thank you so much for pointing this out, otherwise I probably have to stare at this code for hours.

Answer (score 3):

In VBA an instruction is terminated either by a new line, or if you want multiple instructions on a single line, by an *instruction separator* token (i.e. a colon `:` - not that you typically *want* multiple instructions on a single line).

A line of code in VBA can be seen as either a *logical code line*, or a *physical code line*. When a code line gets too wide/lengthy, you can *continue* a *logical* line of code one the next *physical* line of code using the *line continuation* token (a whitespace followed by an underscore `_`).

[As was pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056102/vba-usedrange-run-time-error-438-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method#comment73196856_43056102), most of these lines don't need to be *continued* - in fact, your code only compiles because the continued lines "continue" into a comment, which implicitly terminates the instruction:

> ```
> fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1) _
> 'Name of the temporary workbook
> sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) _
> ```

Remove these comments and your code stops compiling:

```
fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1) _
sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) _
```

...because you can't have two assignments in the same instruction.

So yeah, remove the extraneous line continuations, and problem solved.

---

The specific error you're getting is rather confusing, because `UsedRange` returns an actual `Range` object reference, which gives you all rights to expect a *compile-time* error here instead of *run-time*. Under the hood, this points to the `Range` COM interface being *extensible* - meaning although most member calls are early-bound/resolved at compile-time, VBA lets you make any funky member call on a `Range` object, and defers validation to run-time. Proof:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim bar As Range
    bar.Whatever = 42 ' happily compiles
End Sub
```

This means you need to be especially careful for typos when doing `Range` member calls, because even `Option Explicit` isn't going to help you with that - in other words, **use IntelliSense** / auto-completion whenever referring to known members, to avoid such errors.

Since in VBA identifiers can very well end with an underscore (e.g. `Formula_`), it's only at run-time that VBA queries the `Range` interface and discovers that there's no such thing as a `Formula_` - and boom, error 438.

Comment: I was wondering how this code was actually running. Really nice explanation... as always :)

Comment: @CallumDA thanks! Added a bit about the `Range` interface being extensible, which explains how the code can compile and only fail at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- `_` is used to indicate that a single line statement will continue on the next line. It is rarely needed and you will see below, it's actually not necessary anywhere in your subroutine
- In that vein, ***your actual issue*** is that you have `UsedRange.Formula_` rather than `UsedRange.Formula _` on your error line. Note the missing space
- Your commenting is cluttering your code a bit. Try to only comment on things that explain the less obvious features of your code. Your variables are well named so you don't need to comment that `fileName` is `'Name of the temporary workbook`, for example.

---

```
Sub Sample()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim fileToOpen As Variant
    Dim fileName As String, sheetName As String

    fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If fileToOpen <> False Then
        Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    End If

    fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1)
    sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WB.Sheets("SOE Summary").UsedRange.Value = Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(sheetName).UsedRange.Formula
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Workbooks(fileName).Close savechanges:=False

    WB.Sheets("SOE Summary").UsedRange.Value = WB.Sheets("SOE Summary").UsedRange.Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd even go as far as to say *only comment on the **why**, and let the code say **what*** ;-)